# Spring webflux When to use map over flatmap

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor

I am new to java reactive programming and i have started learning it with spring webflux.
One thing that is always bothering me that map is synchronous while flatmap is asynchronous.

I am learning it from book spring in action chapter 10 and i see the below example.

```
Flux<Player> playerFlux = Flux
.just("Michael Jordan", "Scottie Pippen", "Steve Kerr")
.map(n -> {
String[] split = n.split("\\s");
return new Player(split[0], split[1]);
});
```

and after very next line it says

`What’s important to understand about map() is that the mapping is performed synchronously,
as each item is published by the source Flux. If you want to perform the
mapping asynchronously, you should consider the flatMap() operation.`

and showed this example

```
Flux<Player> playerFlux = Flux
.just("Michael Jordan", "Scottie Pippen", "Steve Kerr")
.flatMap(n -> Mono.just(n)
.map(p -> {
String[] split = p.split("\\s");
return new Player(split[0], split[1]);
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
);
```

Alright i think i got the point, but when i was practicing i think actually i didn't got it. lot of question started to rise in my head when i was trying to populate my class fields.

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Response {

    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    private List data;
}
```

Here is the code how i was trying to populate it

```
Mono<Response> response = Mono.just(new Response())
.map(res -> res.setSuccess(true))
.map(res -> res.setMessage("Success"))
.map(res -> res.setData(new ArrayList()));
```

after writing this code, one line from the book blinks in my head that map its synchronous will it be a blocking code, could it be bad for entire application because once i read that in a non-blocking application single blocking code could ruin the entire app.

So i decided to convert it into flatmap and according to book it should be look like this.

```
Mono<Response> response1 = Mono.just(new Response())
    .flatMap(
            m -> Mono.just(m)
            .map(res -> res.setSuccess(true))
    )
    .flatMap(
            m -> Mono.just(m)
            .map(res -> res.setMessage("Success"))
    )
    .flatMap(
            m -> Mono.just(m)
            .map(res -> res.setData(new ArrayList()))
    );
```

Both example output same but then what is the difference here. it so we should always use flatmap?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` for that inner `Mono` in the `flatMap()`: only this way it becomes asynchronous. And only in this case you will be able to avoid blocking the main flow.

Comment: Setting a simple field is NOT a blocking operation, so `map` operator is a good choice for that purpose. What you need to avoid is doing blocking I/O operations (blocking file read, blocking HTTP call, etc.) on non-blocking threads.

Comment: Hey Martin does it mean if i get data from db in map like spring reactive mongo repository like
map( m - {
Mono<User> user = repo.findById(1);
})

it this map still blocking?